# Get radial distance between vector1 and vector2

Tags: c, game, coordinate-system

A small script to calculate total units of distance between two vector entities. Especially useful in games and grid snaps, inventory snaps etc..

```
typedef struct COORD
{
    int X, Y;
} coord;

int get_dist (coord entity1, coord entity2)
{
    int minuendX    = max(entity1.X, entity2.X);
    int minuendY    = max(entity2.Y, entity2.Y);
    int subtrahendX = min(entity1.X, entity2.X);
    int subtrahendY = min(entity2.Y, entity2.Y);

    return (minuendX - subtrahendX) + (minuendY - subtrahendY);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "radial distance"?

Comment: Well regularly it refers to the euclidean vector but in this case.. a radius.

Comment: Does this code give the intended results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a typo in the y components, both times only entity2 is used. I believe that is a copy-paste error.

Your distance is better known as the manhattan distance. I suggest naming the method after it to avoid surprises.

An other method of getting it uses the absolute value of the differences:

```
int get_manhattan_dist (coord entity1, coord entity2)
{
    return abs(entity1.X - entity2.X) + abs(entity1.Y - entity2.Y);
}
```

Of course if you have the manhattan distance you can easily provide the euclidean distance

```
double get_euclid_dist (coord entity1, coord entity2)
{
    double diffX    = entity1.X - entity2.X;
    double diffY    = entity1.Y - entity2.Y;

    return hypot(diffX, diffY);
}
```

Comment: Oh you are right about the typos. I re-created my code in here. I am testing on the correct version though. Thank you, didn't know of its name.

Comment: Note: `double diffX = entity1.X;  diffX -= entity2.X;` costs 1 more `int/double` conversion, but prevents `int` overflow.

Comment: @chux not really more int->double conversion because hypot takes 2 doubles and the params get converted before the function gets called

Comment: `double diffX    = entity1.X - entity2.X;` employs 1 `int/double` conversion.  `double diffX = entity1.X; diffX -= entity2.X;` uses 2 `int/double` conversions.  The call of `hypot()` does not affect that count.